# Mouseover event with Bodymovin JS

Tags: javascript, svg, hover, onmouseover, bodymovin

I'm looking to add a mouseover event to an SVG that was exported from After Effects. I'd like the SVG to play on `mouseover`. So far, I've played around with the `animation-play-state` attribute but it hasn't worked. I've also tried using `onmouseover` in the script and tried adding an event listener for the `mouseover`, but still nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```
var params = {
    container: document.getElementById('bodymovin'),
    renderer: 'svg',
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    animationData: animationData

};

var anim;

anim = bodymovin.loadAnimation(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this and it works for me:

```
animContainer = document.getElementById('bodymovin');

var params = {
    container: animContainer,
    renderer: 'svg',
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplay:false,
    autoloadSegments: false,
    path: 'data.json'// path to your data.json file you rendered from AE

};

var anim;

anim = bodymovin.loadAnimation(params);
animContainer.addEventListener("mouseover", myScript);

function myScript(){
    anim.play();
}
```